# Cannot inner join two simple CTEs on a field with mixed data types in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

## Problem

I cannot `inner join` two simple CTEs in Snowflake.  Terse error message does not show the way.
***What is wrong with my query?***
<strike>Bonus points: *Why does my query work in SQL Server but not Snowflake?*</strike>

## Background

I am new to Snowflake.  I am used to SQL Server.  I want to query an `inner join` of 2 tables in Snowflake.  Tables 1 and 2 show the tables that I want to join.  Table 3 is the result that I want.

There are some rows with the first table that I want to remove inside a CTE with a simple `where` clause.  When I run my query (see below), I get a verse terse error message:

`Numeric value 'HAHA! IM CAUSING TROUBLE' is not recognized`

But I thought I "removed" this value with my first CTE.

<strike>***What is wrong with my query?*** Bonus points: *Why does my query work in SQL Server but not Snowflake?*</strike>

## Table 1: Field History

| id | date | field_id | field_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | unwanted | HAHA! IM CAUSING TROUBLE |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | thing | 100 |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | thing | 101 |
| 4 | 2020-01-04 | thing | 102 |
| 5 | 2020-01-05 | thing | null |
| 6 | 2020-01-06 | thing | 103 |

## Table 2: Things I Want to Join

| thing_id | thing_start_date | thing_end_date | something_i_care_about |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 | secret alien intelligence |
| 101 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-01 | blueprints for shark lazers |
| 102 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-01 | non-YA biz-NAZZ |
| 103 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-05-01 | who will win bachelorette |

## Table 3: Final Table of My Dreams

| id | date | thing_id | thing_start_date | thing_end_date | something_i_care_about |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | 100 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-02-01 | secret alien intelligence |
| 3 | 2020-01-03 | 101 | 2020-02-01 | 2020-03-01 | blueprints for time machine |
| 4 | 2020-01-04 | 102 | 2020-03-01 | 2020-04-01 | non-YA biz-NAZZ |
| 6 | 2020-01-06 | 103 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-05-01 | who will win bachelorette |

## What I have Tried

```
with field_history as ( -- CTE with simple where clause

  select
      id
      , date
      , to_number(field_value, 38, 0) as thing_id  -- SQL Server equivalent would be cast() or convert()
  from db.schema.history
  where field_id = 'thing' and field_value is not null

),

things_i_want as (

  select
    *
  from db.schema.things

),

final as (
  
  select
    field_history.id
    , field_history.date
    , things.*
  from field_history
  inner join things_i_want on field_history.thing_id = things_i_want.thing_id

)

select * from final
```

## Super Helpful Error Message Blocking me from My Dreams

`Numeric value 'HAHA! IM CAUSING TROUBLE' is not recognized`

Comment: Seems like "to_number" behaves differently on invalid string on the two systems. Try using https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html instead.

Comment: @RomanHocke  Wow.  All that.  And I was just using the wrong conversion function. ‍♂️ Can we delete a post that we are now embarrassed by?  Thank you.  That is what I was missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Numeric value 'HAHA! IM CAUSING TROUBLE' is not recognized

Your error message is a type conversion problem and would appear to be here:

```
to_number(field_value, 38, 0) as thing_id
```

You may think that the `where` clause filters out the bad values.  However, SQL engines can -- and do -- rearrange operations.  I would suggest using a `case` expression to handle this:

```
(case when field_value regexp '^[0-9]+$'
      then to_number(field_value, 38, 0)
 end) as thing_id
```

The `case` expression is guaranteed to run the expressions sequentially.

The above idea (but not the `regexp` part) works in SQL Server and Snowflake.

In Snowflake only, you can use `try_` functions:

```
try_to_number(field_value, 38, 0) as thing_id
```

Comment: Very correct Gordon: Snowflake very much does run the SELECT transforms before the WHERE clauses on variant data (aka json), thus if you columns have mixed types, you have to use the `TRY_x` forms of the casters. Sometime CASE and COALESCE can help you, but then it magically explodes again as it reorders the transforms. So the rule is with data type always TRY to be safe.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim . . . The irony is that SQL Server also pushes a bunch of transformations to the read node in the DAG -- often causing this type of conversion error.  I am surprised the code works in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple error. You are trying to convert a string *'HAHA! IM CAUSING TROUBLE'* to Number. Even if you remove it, you may have future error because of null in the same column in Field_History table. You need to handle that in query. Not sure exactly what query you wrote in SQL Server so can't say why it worked.